# i've tried doing this query but haven't been able to get the expected (or desired) result

Tags: database, linq, list, binding, windows-phone-7.1

i've tried doing this query but haven't been able to get the expected (or desired) result

```
        using (ModelDBDataContext dataContext = new ModelDBDataContext("Data Source='isostore:/PueblosDB.sdf'"))
        {
            if (!dataContext.DatabaseExists())
            {
                dataContext.CreateDatabase();

                List<Pueblo> puebloObj = new List<Pueblo>()
                {
                    new Pueblo()
                    {
                    Id=1, Nombre="Aguadas", Imagen="Recursos/Imagenes/aguadas.png",Descrip="Algo",Coord="Algo"
                    },

                    new Pueblo()
                    {
                    Id=2, Nombre="Villa de Leyva", Imagen="Recursos/Imagenes/Villa de Leyva.png",Descrip="algo",Coord="Algo"
                    }
                 };

                dataContext.Pueblo.InsertAllOnSubmit(puebloObj);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

After create i join the data with the xaml

```
    public List<Pueblo> misPueblos { get; set; }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ModelDBDataContext contextoDatos = new ModelDBDataContext("Data Source='isostore:/PueblosDB.sdf'"))
        {
            misPueblos = contextoDatos.Pueblo.ToList();
        }

        listBox2.ItemsSource = misPueblos;

    }
```

In this place i do the consult using the event tap

```
        var pue = from Pueblo in misPueblos
                  where Pueblo.Id == Convert.ToInt32(id)
                  select (new{Pueblo.Nombre}) ;

        MessageBox.Show("este es el id: " + pue.ToList());
```

Comment: What are you asking ? What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your final snippet, `var pue` is coming out as an enumeration of anonymous objects containing a single string property.  `MessageBox.Show` is trying to construct a string to display but doesn't know what to do with that list.

It appears that your intention is to get a single string property provided a single id.

```
    var pue = from Pueblo in misPueblos
              where Pueblo.Id == Convert.ToInt32(id)
              select Pueblo.Nombre ;

    MessageBox.Show("este es el id: " + pue.FirstOrDefault()??"Not Found");
```

now `var pue` is a simple enumeration of strings, and since you're probably expecting one record, the call to FirstOrDefault converts the enumeration into a single string from the first record, or null if no records found.